# How to retrieve available height considering other UIElement's height?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, height

How can i get the available height?

I tried:

```
NSLog(@"%f", [self bounds].size.height);
NSLog(@"%f", [self frame].size.height);
NSLog(@"%f", [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
```

I get always the screen's height.
But the actual height is smaller. With Informationbar on the top + Nav-Bar, the height is smaller.

**EDIT:
I need to retrieve the height programmatically. Thats if there is a TabBar and my View is not always in a NavBar-Controller. Maybe there is no NavBar.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Navigation bar** has a predefined height of 44 which you can never change. And by **information bar**, i think u mean the **status bar** which has a fixed height of 20. **Total height** of iPhone screen is **480**. U do the calculations... :)

However, if you want the height of such a screen then in the nib always have status bar and navigation bar simulated and then have all the UI elements for that. After that, when you'll do

> self.view.frame.size.height

you'll get the height of your view

Comment: I need to retrieve the height programmatically. Thats if there is a TabBar and my View is not always in a NavBar-Controller. Maybe there is no NavBar.

Comment: Yes, thats what i am telling. When any of your view has a navigation bar, then always show it in the Xib for that file. If it doesnt have then its okay. In this way, u'll have the perfect size for the view. i.e. size will be lesser by 44 pixels. Similar for the tab bar

Comment: Is this also working if i dont use a Xib-File? The View i am creating is dynammically created.

Comment: then u'll be knowing whether that view has a navigation bar or not. Hence, you'll also be knowing the height. If your view is created dynamically, then you will also be setting its frame before you add it to the main view. There you'll be also setting its height which should be a valid height.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.view.frame.size.height;
```

OR

```
float theHeight = // one of the methods you posted
theHeight -= 44; // for nav bar
theHeight -= 20; // for status bar
```